Postgres which is the differene between returns and OUT when there is only one OUT
In question How to generate an array of given size, with one field populated? I have been instructed to write instead of a "returns" an "OUT" statement for a function definition.
The reason was that in that case I may assign to the OUT variable an anyarray "type" that seems impossible to do with return.
As I see that OUT is more flexible than "returns" I am wandering if I may use it for all my functions or if there is any drawback or difference that I do not understand.
By the way, I have to note that when there is only one OUT it seems to me that the result is exactly equal to return, while instead if there are more OUT then the output is a 'record' of the OUTs.
In order to understand without reading the above question, I repeat bellow the code in question:
My tentative wrong initial code was:
create function arraycol(v anyelement,n int,i int) returns anyarray language plpgsql

and it has been exchanged with
create function arraycol(v anyelement,n int,i int,OUT r anyarray)   language plpgsql

TO RESUME may I change all returns to OUT ? and forget about return forever ?

You should only use an OUT parameter declaration if you actually need the variable in the function body

with return you can use the function in a expression or in the return part of the select:
select arraycol(....) from ... ;
or
select ccccc from tttt where col1=arraycol(....);
whereas with OUT you need to use variable to catch the returned value.

Not exactly, the return of the function having OUT does return the OUT variable.
